# Mongo aggregation based on Dates between on more Collections

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data, aggregation, spring-mongodb

I'm using Mongo Aggregation with Spring Data to retrieve data from 4 collections.
My problem is that I want to add a filter based on the *createdAt* on 3 of these collections.
Here the examples:

**Animal**

```
{"_id":123,"name":"Lucky","age":3,createdAt:"2022-02-01 10:00:00.000Z"}
{"_id":456,"name":"Joe","age":5,createdAt:"2022-02-10 20:03:00.000Z"}
```

**Cat**

```
{"idAnimal":123,"toy":6,createdAt:"2022-03-01 10:00:40.000Z"}
{"idAnimal":456,"toy":2,createdAt:"2022-02-10 20:05:00.000Z"}
```

**Pet**

```
{"idAnimal":123,"meal":3,"medicine":false,createdAt:"2022-03-01 10:00:40.000Z"}
{"idAnimal":456,"meal":4,"medicine":true,createdAt:"2022-02-10 20:05:00.000Z"}
```

What I mean to do is to get all the Animals with a Pet collection created gte(2022-03-01). The expected result would be the first cat, Lucky.
In my code I tried this

```
final List<Criteria> criteria = new ArrayList<>();
criteria.add(new Criteria().orOperator(
                    Criteria.where("createdAt").gte("2022-03-01").lte("2022-03-02"),
                    Criteria.where("Cat.createdAt").gte("2022-03-01").lte("2022-03-02"),
                    Criteria.where("Pet.createdAt").gte("2022-03-01").lte("2022-03-02")
            ));
```

and my Aggregation set up is:

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                Aggregation.lookup("cat", "_id", "idAnimal", "Cat"),
                Aggregation.lookup("pet", "_id", "idAnimal", "Pet"),
                Aggregation.unwind("$_id"),
                Aggregation.match(new Criteria().andOperator(criteria.toArray(new Criteria[0]))
                )
        );
```

I tried to swap the criteria, querying the Pet first, but didn't go as expected. When I run this, I get no result.
Do you have any tips? ***Is it possibile to execute an aggregation on Dates over multiple collections?***
Thank you in advance!

Comment: To compare date data, the types of the fields must be same - in the database and also in the filter criteria (Yes, you can do aggregation query over multiple collections using the `$lookup` and "join" over a _date_ field).

Comment: Thanks @prasad_ , did you look at my code? In the MongoDB all three createdAt are of Date type and the variable I'm passing in gte/lte is a LocalDateTime.

Comment: `LocalDateTime` ? I see it only in your above comment. The date data you are using is of type `String` - `Criteria.where("createdAt").gte("2022-03-01").lte("2022-03-02")`. So, make sure your database date data is also of type ` string`. In case the date data is of type string, then make sure the format is same.

Comment: @prasad_ The code above is an example and when executed it's logged like this, not as ISODate("2022-03-01"). Do you have any tip about how to query over multiple collections in the same aggregation and on the createdAt?

Comment: In your lookup use the `createdAt` field (to compare) instead of the existing `"_id", "idAnimal",` fields.

Comment: This doesn't seems right, I'm already querying with the .orOperator() as in my question on other fields and it works properly: I just have troubles with the Dates and I would like to understand why.

Comment: The `$lookup` has another syntax, and it has a parameter called `pipeline`. This pipeline can accept multiple conditions - there you can specify conditions for each collection.